# What happens when a stream opened by file io is blocked?

Tags: php, file-io, stream, popen

Consider the code snippet here:

```
$handle = popen("some command that generates an infinite stream of output to stdout", "r");

while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
     echo $line;
     sleep(3);
}
```

My question is: what is actually happening during that sleep(3) and the command passed to popen() is still spewing output? Is that getting buffered to PHP's memory?

Is there a chance the output is trashed?

Answer (score 1):

It's OS-dependent. The data may be buffered, the other program's output calls may block, or some combination thereof.

Comment: Is there a chance the data is trashed?

Comment: Only if the program disables blocking on output and doesn't retry.

Comment: How can we find out whether the popen'd program will get blocked? I ask because I want to popen a network traffic analyzer, so if it gets blocked it will miss out on data

Comment: The only way to be certain is to examine the source code of the program in question.